# Application is not taken layout-sw600dp-land folder xml file?

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I am developing an application for smartphones and tablets devices. In tablet device purpose using `layout-sw600dp-port` and `layout-sw600dp-land` folders,in app running portrait taken folder correctly in landscape mode is not taken ,its taken default. How to resolve the issue? please send any other alternatives.

Comment: the device where you are running it, has Android 3.2+?

Comment: I am using samsung tab model GT-P3100 version 4.1.2.

Comment: do you have the configChanges="screenSize|orientation" inside your manifest?

Comment: <activity android:name=".Shipment_Details"
               android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />

Comment: remove orinetaion . That works only if android can restart the activity

Comment: I am using two different xml files both potrait and landscape

Comment: you have to open your AndroidManifest.xml file and delete android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"

Comment: already remove but its not taken layout-sw600dp-land.

Comment: clean & rebuild and try again. That's all I can say from the context you provided

Comment: Hi rkn any alternative for getting folder

Answer (score 0):

Define  android:minSdkVersion="8" in android manifest.